# Get Date from Internet and compare to System Clock on Workbook Open

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that uses the current date, finds the next Sunday and puts the following Sunday as the week ending date. This date automatically rolls every Sunday at midnight. Some users are attempting to do a system clock rollback to allot themselves opportunity to falsify certain bits of data entered on my form.

I'd like to pull the date from the internet, compare it to the system date, and then use whichever is later. I struggle getting the VBA together to pull the date from the internet, and I have a function in place that detects a connection. I also have the end of the script which disables the 'send email' macro so they cannot email off the report (which they couldn't without Internet). I did borrow some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190812/pickup-time-from-internet-servers-vba-excel) in an attempt to achieve this, but I'm having trouble making sense of the best application without having to go through a long process.

How do I best solve the collection of a date from the internet for comparing against a potential system clock rollback?

```
---- Function IsInternetConnected()----

Sub CheckTimeDate()

Dim NewDate
Dim NewTime
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws5 As Worksheet
Dim wkEnd As Range
Dim http

    Const NetTime As String = "https://www.time.gov/"

On Error Resume Next
Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

http.Open "GET", NetTime & Now(), False, "", ""
http.send

NewTime = http.getResponseHeader("Date")

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")
Set wkEnd = ws1.Range("J3")

If IsInternetConnected() = True Then
    NewDate = NetDate
    ws1.wkEnd = .Value.NewDate

    ElseIf IsInternetConnected() = False Then

    On Error GoTo SysClockRollback
        wkEnd = Value.Date
    ElseIf NewDate > Date Then wkEnd = NewDate.Value
    Else: wkEnd = .Value.Date
    End If

Set ws1 = Nothing
Set wkEnd = Nothing
Set NetTime = Nothing

SysClockRollback:
MsgBox "The system clock appears to be incorrect. If the system clock was rolled back. This form will now use the local internet time for all dates. "

End Sub

----Sub SendMail()----
If IsInternetConnected() = False Then
    MsgBox "There is no Internet connection detected." & vbNewLine & _
    vbNewline & _
    "Please connect to the internet before sending.", vbApplicationModal, vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
Else:
...and it goes into the SendMail Sub from there...
```

The point of exiting the SendMail sub when no internet is detected is so that they cannot initiate the process of sending an email and then saving the altered dates as a draft for later. I want to force the correct dates, and I'm not latching on to some of these concepts

Comment: Duplicate question, already answered here: "How can I find user's time zone offset in excel" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532038/how-can-i-find-users-time-zone-offset-in-excel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find user's time zone offset in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532038/how-can-i-find-users-time-zone-offset-in-excel)

Comment: I don't need the timezone offset. I only needed the TZ to ensure a more accurate date for certain hours from each day. I understand how it could be perceived that this was a duplicate question, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do this in steps

1. Get UTC time from internet
2. Convert UTC to local time, taking into account DST
3. Compare tho PC clock
4. Apply a tolerance

**UTC time fuctions** [from cpearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TimeZoneAndDaylightTime.aspx)

```
Private Type SYSTEMTIME
    wYear As Integer
    wMonth As Integer
    wDayOfWeek As Integer
    wDay As Integer
    wHour As Integer
    wMinute As Integer
    wSecond As Integer
    wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type

Private Type TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
    Bias As Long
    StandardName(0 To 31) As Integer
    StandardDate As SYSTEMTIME
    StandardBias As Long
    DaylightName(0 To 31) As Integer
    DaylightDate As SYSTEMTIME
    DaylightBias As Long
End Type

Private Enum TIME_ZONE
    TIME_ZONE_ID_INVALID = 0
    TIME_ZONE_STANDARD = 1
    TIME_ZONE_DAYLIGHT = 2
End Enum
Private Type DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
    Bias As Long
    StandardName As String
    StandardDate As Date
    StandardBias As Long
    DaylightName As String
    DaylightDate As Date
    DaylightBias As Long
    TimeZoneKeyName As String
    DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function GetTimeZoneInformationForYear Lib "kernel32" ( _
    wYear As Integer, _
    lpDynamicTimeZoneInformation As DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION, _
    lpTimeZoneInformation As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION _
) As Long

Private Declare Function GetTimeZoneInformation Lib "kernel32" _
        (lpTimeZoneInformation As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION) As Long

Private Declare Sub GetSystemTime Lib "kernel32" _
        (lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)

Function LocalOffsetFromGMT(Optional AsHours As Boolean = False, _
  Optional AdjustForDST As Boolean = False) As Double
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' LocalOffsetFromGMT
    ' This returns the amount of time in minutes (if AsHours is omitted or
    ' false) or hours (if AsHours is True) that should be *added* to the
    ' local time to get GMT. If AdjustForDST is missing or false,
    ' the unmodified difference is returned. (e.g., Kansas City to London
    ' is 6 hours normally, 5 hours during DST. If AdjustForDST is False,
    ' the resultif 6 hours. If AdjustForDST is True, the result is 5 hours
    ' if DST is in effect.)
    ' Note that the return type of the function is a Double not a Long. This
    ' is to accomodate those few places in the world where the GMT offset
    ' is not an even hour, such as Newfoundland, Canada, where the offset is
    ' on a half-hour displacement.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Dim TBias As Long
    Dim TZI As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
    Dim DST As TIME_ZONE
    DST = GetTimeZoneInformation(TZI)

    If DST = TIME_ZONE_DAYLIGHT Then
        If AdjustForDST = True Then
            TBias = TZI.Bias + TZI.DaylightBias
        Else
            TBias = TZI.Bias
        End If
    Else
        TBias = TZI.Bias
    End If
    If AsHours = True Then
        TBias = TBias / 60
    End If

    LocalOffsetFromGMT = TBias
End Function
```

**Internet Time** your code tidied up

```
Function GetUCTTimeDate() As Date
    Dim UTCDateTime As String
    Dim arrDT() As String
    Dim http As Object
    Dim UTCDate As String
    Dim UTCTime As String

    Const NetTime As String = "https://www.time.gov/"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    On Error GoTo 0

    http.Open "GET", NetTime & Now(), False, "", ""
    http.send

    UTCDateTime = http.getResponseHeader("Date")
    UTCDate = Mid(UTCDateTime, InStr(UTCDateTime, ",") + 2)
    UTCDate = Left(UTCDate, InStrRev(UTCDate, " ") - 1)
    UTCTime = Mid(UTCDate, InStrRev(UTCDate, " ") + 1)
    UTCDate = Left(UTCDate, InStrRev(UTCDate, " ") - 1)
    GetUCTTimeDate = DateValue(UTCDate) + TimeValue(UTCTime)
End Function
```

**Compare Times**

```
Function ClockDiff() As Double ' In Minutes
    Dim InternetDT As Date
    Dim UTC As Date
    Dim off As Double

    UTC = GetUCTTimeDate
    off = LocalOffsetFromGMT(True, True)
    InternetDT = DateAdd("h", -off, UTC)
    ClockDiff = DateDiff("n", Now(), InternetDT)
End Function
```

**Put it all together**

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim PcClockDiff As Double
    Const TOLERANCE = 10 ' minutes

    PcClockDiff = Abs(ClockDiff)
    If PcClockDiff > TOLERANCE Then
        MsgBox "Clock has been changed..."
    Else
        MsgBox "Clock is OK"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In some instances, it seems that after 10PM system clock time, the GetUCTTimeDate returns a day ahead of clock but the Demo subroutine will still read "Clock is OK." I'm going to investigate a way to mitigate that from the code here, but otherwise, that's a snappy solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was just toying around with a similar idea and though along the lines of keeping a track of the current system time on a very hidden sheet whenever the workbook is opened.
If they try to roll back the clock to a date/time before the last time they opened the file then the file closes.

```
Sub datee()

Dim lastrow As Long
With Sheets("sheet1")

lastrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A"))

.Range("a" & lastrow).Offset(1, 0).Value = Now


If Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range("A:A")) > Now Then
        MsgBox ("Date has been tampered with")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Date appears good")
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

The only problem with it in this instance would be the the chance to tamper with the date before opening the file.

Comment: What if theres no notification that the sheet detects tampering at all, and just forces a system clock update?