# Need someone to make a code for vb that takes the current live date instead of the system date

Tags: excel, vba

Need help with this topic so willing to hire for this project,
the function =NOW() in excel won't work for me as I need a way to get the current date instead of the system date so that's what I am looking for.

Comment: I don't know how to explain it better but the thing is in excel the function =NOW() will not work as I need a way for my file to verify that the sheet is open on the exact same date as I

Comment: Details means that your question should provide an explanation of the problem, including what you tried and what is not working as you expect.

Comment: have created a calculator which can exactly calculate the trend reversal point in the stock market so as covid is going on I was going to release it but i don't want to give it out for free so i need to make a failsafe to protect the doc

Comment: so I require the code which will verify the current date with online servers and tally it with the system date and verify that both are the same

Comment: "Need someone to make a code…"—no, this is _your_ job. We're not here to write code for you. Please take the [tour].

Comment: "willing to hire for this project"—this edit doesn't help. Stack Overflow isn't a job board any more than it's a place to get code written for you. _Again_, please take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

The following code will give you the **system** date & time.

```
Sub DateAndTime()
    Cells(1, 1) = Now()
    Cells(2, 1) = Date
End Sub
```

Below is a solution to your problem from the following link:
[Get Date from Internet and compare to System Clock on Workbook Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48371398/get-date-from-internet-and-compare-to-system-clock-on-workbook-open)

```
Function GetUCTTimeDate() As Date
    Dim UTCDateTime As String
    Dim arrDT() As String
    Dim http As Object
    Dim UTCDate As String
    Dim UTCTime As String

    Const NetTime As String = "https://www.time.gov/"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    On Error GoTo 0

    http.Open "GET", NetTime & Now(), False, "", ""
    http.send

    UTCDateTime = http.getResponseHeader("Date")
    UTCDate = Mid(UTCDateTime, InStr(UTCDateTime, ",") + 2)
    UTCDate = Left(UTCDate, InStrRev(UTCDate, " ") - 1)
    UTCTime = Mid(UTCDate, InStrRev(UTCDate, " ") + 1)
    UTCDate = Left(UTCDate, InStrRev(UTCDate, " ") - 1)
    GetUCTTimeDate = DateValue(UTCDate) + TimeValue(UTCTime)
End Function
```

You may want to look at the following link before writing questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites